how to implement linkedin api function for creating a reaction on a share/comment?
I've tried implement functions to use linkedin api call to create a reaction on a share or a comment as per linkedin api documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/reactions-api?view=li-lms-2024-09&tabs=http#create-a-reaction-on-a-share.
I've already have access to linkedin community management api.
The functions:

const LINKEDIN_USER_URN = 'urn:li:person:abcxyz'

const postReactionOnComment = async (postId, commentId, reactionType) => {
    const payload = {
        "root": `urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:${postId},${commentId})`,
        "reactionType": reactionType
    };

    try {
        // Log the URL and payload
        console.log("Requesting URL (Comment Reaction):", `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions?actor=${encodeURIComponent(LINKEDIN_USER_URN)}`);
        console.log("Payload (Comment Reaction):", payload);

        const response = await axios.post(`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions?actor=${encodeURIComponent(LINKEDIN_USER_URN)}`, payload, setLinkedInHeaders());
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error posting reaction on comment:", error.message);
        throw new Error('Failed to post reaction on comment');
    }
};

const postReactionOnShare = async (shareId, reactionType) => {
    const payload = {
        "root": `urn:li:activity:${shareId}`,
        "reactionType": reactionType
    };

    try {
        // Log the URL and payload
        console.log("Requesting URL (Share Reaction):", `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions?actor=${encodeURIComponent(LINKEDIN_USER_URN)}`);
        console.log("Payload (Share Reaction):", payload);

        const response = await axios.post(`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions?actor=${encodeURIComponent(LINKEDIN_USER_URN)}`, payload, setLinkedInHeaders());
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error posting reaction on share:", error.message);
        throw new Error('Failed to post reaction on share');
    }
};

but when I run test case for these two functions it comes back as Request failed with status code 404
Can you guys please let me know what I've done wrong and possible fix?
